# Overlap data transfer and kernel execution using CUDA stream

Tags: cuda

I want to optimize my `CUDA` program by overlapping data transfer with kernel execution. But the sample program `asyncAPI.cu` in CUDA SDK is too simple to help.

I did search this problem, and found some tutorials use two CUDA streams to achieve overlapping. In my case, a huge amount of data need to be computed, so I need to loop through and dispatch a portion of data to `GPU` each iteration. But I don't how to write such a loop, because all operations are asynchronous and I am afraid the transferring data will erase/cover those currently under computing.

Does any one has experienced this?
Any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you should keep in mind is that operations in the same stream will be executed in order and will only overlap with operations in other streams. When I worked with streams my approach was to have separate memory locations for each stream to use. This would eliminate problems of synchronization between streams. If this is not an option for you because of memory constraints or you need to share data between kernels you have to program synchronization yourself.

Also, if you do any calls on the default stream this steam will wait for all other streams to finish before executing and no other streams can execute while there is something running on the default stream.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In more detail, you may also have, for example, a single array for your input/output, and each stream receives a different offset into those arrays.  The offset should be calculated based on the number of elements processed by kernels in each stream, so that no threads in one stream ever touch memory used by the other stream(s).

Comment: Yes, I got. Thanks a lot. But, while in a loop when to start the next data transfer. A piece of code snippet will help.

Comment: @harrism: Sound reasonable. Another question, control return to host immediately, and if in a loop will start next data transfer before the previous one finished. So, how to control this situation. To polling event? Or there are better solutions? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to do polling yourself. You can use cuda events (cudaEvent_t, refer to section 3.2.5 of the CUDA programming guide 4.0). In the CUDA SDK there are (in v4.0, not sure about other versions) at least two more examples that might be helpful: concurrentKernels and simpleMultiCopy. simpleMultiCopy is what I think you are looking for (copy and execution inside a for loop).

Comment: @harrism Yes You are correct !but how to it in 2D array,allocating chunk i.e tile to stream seems very difficult because in case 1D array we can simply have base pointer of that portion of data as one of argument of kernel but how to acheive this in case of 2D array?

Comment: You can always linearize 2D addresses to 1D offsets in memory, so I don't see any problem with doing this in 2D or any number of dimensions.